# Woocommerce checkout ajax callback

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a javascript callback for the ajax action (when you change the shipping) on the woocommerce checkout? And how do you hook into that callback?

Comment: Yes. [`updated_shipping_method`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/assets/js/frontend/cart.js#L35) runs when the shipping method is changed.

Comment: Looks good but it seems that this is only triggered in the cart not in the checkout? i am not able to bind anything to that trigger.

Comment: Just digged into the code and it seems that there is a trigger called "update_checkout" ... probably they removed your trigger in newer versions? Anyway. Thank you Sir ;) you brought me on the right track.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
jQuery( document ).on( 'updated_checkout', function() {

    console.log( 'here goes a action' );

} );
```